# CommandButton does not invoke javascript in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf

The declaration and the invoke is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>#{msgs.windowTitle}</title>
  <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="Resources/js/checkPassword.js" />
</head>

<body>
<h3>#{msgs.Entrance}</h3><br/><br/><br/>
<h:form>

<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnsClasses="evenColumns, oddColumns">

#{msgs.namePrompt}
<h:inputText/>

#{msgs.PasswordPrompt}
<h:inputSecret id="password" />

#{msgs.ConfirmPasswordPrompt}
<h:inputSecret id="passwordConfirm"/>

</h:panelGrid>

<h:commandButton type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkPassword()" />
    </h:form>
    </body>

</html>
```

The checkpassdword.js

```
 function checkPassword(){
        alert("here it is");
        var password = form[form.id+":passwordConfirm"].value;

        var passwordConfirm = form[form.id+":password"].value;
        if(password==passwordConfirm){
            form.submit();
        }
        else{
            alert("Wrong");
        } 

    }
```

It is inside `WebContent/Resources/js`

when i write in put and, click button, nothing happens.

In explorer the error is in console

```
<script src="RES_NOT_FOUND" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can i solve this problem? I tried to put in src, webinf, meta inf and tried to declare as src not name but nothing happened.

The error unidentified checkPassword.

Comment: Try: `<script type="text/javascript"> your.script.here </script>` within the `head` of your page.

Comment: Or if you are using a jsp page. You could use `<jsp:include page="Resources/js/checkpassdword.js" />` also in the head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<h:outputScript library="javascript" name="Resources/js/checkPassword.js" />
```

with

```
 <h:outputScript name="js/checkPassword.js"/>
```

and rename your `Resources` folder in your WebContent into `resources`

And go over the following thread [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)